# CakePHP 2.1 $this->Session->write is not working

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I included the 'Session' Component and the helper in my AppController.php
Now, if I use `$this->Session->write('App.testString', 'test);` the Session is not created, or at least I don't receive the string when I do `echo $this->Session->read('App.testString');`.

Do I have to change any settings for Sessions to work?

---

Inside a controller function I can write and read a session, but if I want to read the session inside a different function (of the same controller) I don't get a value back.

Comment: you need to tell us about your core.php settings (how is your session configured?).

Comment: Ah sorry. I figured it out and as you suggested, the core.php was the reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution: By default CakePHP uses the folder which is set in php.ini. This folder couldn't be accessed in my hosting-environment (and I was not allowed to change the php.ini).

In this situation, you have to change in the **core.php** where session files are stored. This is what I had before:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

I changed it to this one:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

This way, cake uses his own tmp-folder to store the session files. Also make sure that the tmp folder and his subfolders are writeable.